# sympy - Bisection method - TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, typeerror, sympy

I'm trying to implement Bisection method with Sympy but I have this error:

```
if f[a]*f[c] > 0:  # Opposite sign a and c
File "C:\Users\maico\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 376, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Here is my code:

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, latex, lambdify, Float
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex

eq = input("Latex equation: ")    
raw_equation = eq.replace("=0", "").replace("= 0", "").replace("e", "E")
equation = parse_latex("y = " + raw_equation)
f = lambdify(x, parse_latex(self.__raw_equation), 'numpy')

# Bisection
a = 0 # start interval
b = 1 # end interval

eps = a - b
r = None
nlimit = 8
for n in range(nlimit):
    c = (a + b) / 2
    fd = {a: f(a), b: f(b), c: f(c)}
    solved = False
    for v in [a, b, c]:
        if fd[v] == 0:
            r = "Iterations: {} - Result: {}".format(n + 1, v)
            solved = True
            break
    if solved:
        break
    if fd[a]*fd[c] > 0:  # Opposite sign a and c <-- ERROR
        b = c
    else:  # Opposite sign b and c
        a = c
...
```

You can test this with the following equation: `xe^x-1=0`

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: You are redefining your lambda function `f` as a dictionary and that is going to cause problems.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. My code is organized in classes so I've overwritten it. I'll fix it now

Comment: Where does your use of `sympy` end, and strictly numeric work (python and numpy) start?  With the `lambdify` you appear to switch, but the error indicates that you still have sympy objects in `fd[a]*fd[c]`.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided `equation` in `sympy` form, or even `f` as a `numpy` function.  I don't have enough `latex` related packages installed to run your code as given.

Comment: Show `print(f.__doc__)` to see what the `lambdify` has produced.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the bisection routine in SymPy? Then you build off of an established routine. Your routine does not work and you can verify that with `f = lambda x: x-0.6` and `a=0`,'b=1` for which the final values for `a,b,c` are `(0, 0.00390625, 0.00390625)`.

Comment: @hpaulj the equation in sympy form is `E**x*x - 1`. The print returns
```Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x)

Expression:

E**x*x - 1

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return (E**x*x - 1)


Imported modules:
```

@smichr what do you mean with bisection routine in SymPy?

Comment: How or where is `E` defined?  I get the error when it is a `sympy.symbol`, but not if it is the `sympy` `exp` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these imports:

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, latex, lambdify, Float
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex

E = symbols('E')
equation = E**x*x - 1
f = lambdify(x, equation, 'numpy')
print(f.__doc__)
....
```

I get:

```
1450:~/mypy$ python3 stack61370217.py 
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x)

Expression:

E**x*x - 1

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return (E**x*x - 1)


Imported modules:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack61370217.py", line 29, in <module>
    if fd[a]*fd[c] > 0:  # Opposite sign a and c <-- ERROR
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 376, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

If instead

```
from sympy import E
```

the lambdified expression becomes

```
def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return (x*exp(x) - 1)
```

it runs producing `c` `0.00390625`

You don't show the definition of `E`.  I don't know if the latex parsing produce it or not.  I don't have have enough packages installed to run that.  In any case, that symbolic `E` propagates through to the `numpy` expression,

```
In [86]: E=symbols('E')                                                                                

In [87]: def f(x): 
    ...:     return E**x*x-1 
    ...:                                                                                               

In [88]: f(10)                                                                                         
Out[88]: 
    10    
10⋅E   - 1

In [89]: f(10)*f(20)>0                                                                                 
Out[89]: 
⎛    10    ⎞ ⎛    20    ⎞    
⎝10⋅E   - 1⎠⋅⎝20⋅E   - 1⎠ > 0

In [90]: if f(10)*f(20)>0: pass                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-14ce5e03fbac> in <module>
----> 1 if f(10)*f(20)>0: pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    374 
    375     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 376         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    377 
    378     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

If instead `E` is the sympy defined `e`, that gets translated as `exp(x)`, and things run fine.

Comment: @hpaulij I've found out that there is an issue with exp and the parse_latex function: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15604. However, I need to get the input from the user and Latex is a convenient and simple way to write an equation. Do you know a method to replace E with exp in the Sympy generated equation?

Comment: UPDATE: I've found a way, a bit ugly, but it works: https://pastebin.com/92XfTadh.
Than you @hpaulij for your help!